# How do I downscale a BufferedImage to a specific number of pixels

Tags: java, image-processing, pixel, bufferedimage

I have an Image of 1000px X 1000px how do I go about and shrink it down to say 250x250 pixels and get an useable array of rgb colors values out of that

I tried using Java's Graphics2D but it turns out that doesn't actually reduce the amount of pixels

```
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D gra = result.createGraphics();
gra.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("")), 0, 0, 128, 128, null);
gra.dispose();
System.out.println(ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File("")));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted works, you just need to properly specify the filename. I pointed it to a an image that was 3024x3024 and it saved as a 128x128 image.

```
    BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gra = result.createGraphics();
    gra.drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp/3024x3024.jpeg")), 0, 0, 128, 128, null);
    gra.dispose();
    System.out.println(ImageIO.write(result, "png", new File("/tmp/128x128.png")));
```

Comment: But is the amount of pixels 128x128 ? In that case how do I get an array out of it ?

Comment: The dimensions are defined when you construct the BufferedImage. You can drawImage and drawText and performs lots of other edit operations, but the size "canvas" on to which those things are written will always remain the same. If what you are actually looking for is an array of pixels, then you can use byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

Comment: Two things to remember: 1) `Graphics2D.drawImage()` might return before it's done drawing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532757/how-to-tell-when-graphics-drawimage-has-actually-completed) 2) Using any format with Alpha channel (ARGB, RGBA etc) will prevent you from saving to image formats that have no alpha channels (like JPEG)